# ".www..." Cookie tried to set to another domain

Tags: codenameone

Nothing urgent, not even a problem but a bit annoying.

I noticed a warning in the output console

> Warning: Cookie tried to set to another domain* that's triggered from a `System.out.println` at https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/bb69ac5f8435198b79d29af0a4228502c92bd552/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.java#L1195.

Looking at the culprit, I see it's coming from a request to *https://www.google.com/* that's coming back with the cookie `AEC=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.google.com* (dot www...).
Can we get rid of this?

Comment: I think this would work best as an issue or a pull request. I guess the `.` syntax needs support here as the warning does have some merit for other cases

Comment: Thanks, Shai. Done  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3565